# Cannot connect to SQL Server in AWS cloud

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, connection, cloud

I cannot connect to an SQL Server 2014 database in the AWS Cloud.  A colleague can, but myself and another colleague cannot.  We have check 1433 and 1434 are allowed by the firewall and that looks ok and just wanted to know what else could be checked?

At the moment I do not have SQL server installed locally because I did not think it would be necessary because we are trying to connect to one in the cloud, but my colleague who also cannot connect is finding the same problem and they have a local version of SQL server 2014 installed on their machine which they are able to connect to.

The colleague who this works for could only suggest the ports so we are running out of options.

Thanks

Comment: What are the rules added for the security group of the machine having the SQL Server ? and is it VPC of EC2 ?

Comment: Are both you and your colleague using the same public IP address to connect?  If you both go to Google and type in "what is my IP address" does it show the same IP or a different one?  If it's a different one then make sure the security group(s) for the SQL server are allowing connections from both IP's.

Comment: Are you and the successful colleague on the same network? If not, maybe you are routing through a proxy that doesn't allow outbound 1433.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  We are still investigating at the moment, but have found that the people who cannot access are connecting via a different corporate VPN than the ones who can.  So looks like the likely cause.